# Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, setuptools

Since updating from Homebrew Python 2.7.11 (from 2.7.10) I'm suddenly unable to test register my package on PyPi from the PyCharm IDE console.

Running (as an "External Tool")

```
python -B setup.py register -r pypitest
```

I now get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 17, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. I only get this issue if I execute from within my IDE's console. If I do it directly at the system command line (Terminal on OS X) I have no problems.

---

OS X 10.11.3; Homebrew Python 2.7.11; PyCharm 5.0.3

Comment: Reported [as a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18075).

Comment: I had the same error, also on OS X: virtualenv was not working for me under anaconda - I wouldn't need it with anaconda, but I couldn't [install pants](https://pantsbuild.github.io/install.html) whose installer is using virtualenv. After downgrading from python 2.7.11 to 2.7.10 in a conda env, the problem was solved...

Comment: This seem to happen after each Python update.

Comment: Using the full path to the interpreter in the definition of the external tool seem to fix this (though it's not clear [why that should be necessary](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18042)).

Comment: I got this error trying to install Python for using the Mozilla Firefox build program. The most upvoted answer worked for me as well.

Answer (score 198):

**tl;dr: Fix this issue by doing one of the following:**

- type `hash -r python`, OR
- log out and log in.

**EDIT:** An answer to my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861128/osx-invoking-python-command-from) makes it clear what's happening here.  When you install a new version of python, you may need to run `hash -r python` to tell bash to reset the "cached" location to the `python` executable.

In my case, I was typing `python`, which was on my `$PATH` at `/usr/local/bin/python`.  But `bash` was still using the old cache location `/usr/bin/python`.  So, the old executable was called, but the **new** path was provided to python in `sys.argv[0]`.  This means that the old executable was running, but the new `sys.executable` value caused all the wrong modules to get loaded (including the `io` module).

---

I'm having the same problem.  I installed python 2.7.11 via an installer from Python.org.  Strangely, the issue seems to be related to some subtle difference between how OSX launches `python` when I invoke it from the shell using the full path vs. using just the word `python`.

So, for me, this works (invoking python via the full path `/usr/local/bin/python`):

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ /usr/local/bin/python -c "import io"
$
```

... but this doesn't:

```
$ python -c "import io"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

So, as a workaround, you can try doing the same thing.

Elsewhere, I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861128/osx-invoking-python-command-from) about this puzzling behavior.  Maybe somehow merely calling `python` invokes some strange mix of the 2.7.11 executable with the 2.7.10 dylibs??

Comment: login and logout worked. Notably I had installed python using brew during the session.

Comment: Also see https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/

Comment: Gotta love StackOverflow!!

Comment: if `hash -r python` says too many args, you can use `rehash` command.

Answer (score 21):

According to https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/634:

> I had the same issue, but successfully fixed. In my case I compiled
>   python and vim with homebrew, when PYTHON_PATH has been specified and
>   set to one of my dev environments, where I also had some libraries,
>   including io. Workaround was simple: open new terminal, make sure that
>   you do not have custom PYTHON_PATH, uninstall python, uninstall vim.
>   Reinstall both of them.

and

> Problem solved.
>
> Culprit is the update from python 2.7.10 to 2.7.11.
>
> If you are using conda package control, simply run "conda install
>   python=2.7.10" will solve this problem.

This doesn't give the root cause though. Since this happens with `_io`, this looks like a bug in python 2.7.11 (unlikely, there would be a world-scale outcry and a prompt fix if it was) or some packaging bug or version mismatch specifically with the homebrew version (and maybe some related ones, too).

Try to `import _io` in the console and if it succeeds, check if it was loaded from the same path.

Comment: Weirdly, I only get this issue if I execute from within my IDE's console. If I do it directly at the system command line (Terminal on OS X) I have no problems. I suspect the path in my IDE.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius check environments, executable paths and `sys.path` for differences.

Comment: Also checking [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18042), since it's IDE-specific.

Comment: thank you @ivan_pozdeev. Downgrading from python 2.7.11 to 2.7.10 fixed the problem

Comment: @Codious-JR How did you downgrade? I am having the hardest time figuring that out (using homebrew, not conda)

Comment: I'm not using anaconda, tho at this point I'm starting to think installing it will be my easiest path forward since homebrew doesn't have previous versions of python "on tap"

Comment: hey @skybondsor, i am using anaconda, so the command conda install python=2.7.10 worked for me. Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use anaconda? cause otherwise i really recommend using it.

Comment: @skybondsor I found the previous releases page on python.org, here you can find the mac installer for the version  2.7.10. [python version 2.7.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/)

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that bash's `hash` cache can become incorrect immediately after you install a new version of python.  (Try `type python` to verify that's the problem.)  The person you quoted may have accidentally fixed this via all the uninstalling/reinstalling they described, but the straightforward fix is to type `hash -r python` into the terminal.

Comment: I had installed `macvim` using an older version of Python and after upgrading Python, my vim was giving me this error every time when a plugin wanted to use python modules. Running `brew upgrade macvim` upgraded my vim to be built using the updated python path. This fixed the issue for me. PS: At least for me, it was not a bash caching issue as mentioned in the above post.

Answer (score 12):

Reinstall python.

```
brew unlink python && brew reinstall python
```

Secure the path

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/bin/
```

*BACKUP* and Change the order of "paths" file.

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

it seems, the order of paths, it is decisive to run python properly. In my case, the result was:

```
#sudo nano /etc/paths
  /usr/bin  
  /usr/local/bin
  /bin
  /usr/sbin
  /sbin
```

On my mac, path is like this.

```
$ which python
    /usr/local/bin/python
```

Now I can run both:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python -c "import io"
$ python -c "import io"
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, it is successfully fixed by just replacing the _io.so file.

```
sudo find / -name _io.so
```

copy the path of the `_io.so` file which **DOES NOT** belong to python-2.7.11. For example, copy the path of _io.so which is under python-2.7.5:
 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so

Replace the `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so` file with the `_io.so` that you just found.

Comment: Mixing and matching extension modules from Python 2.7.11 and the system Python, which is 2.7.10 on recent systems, is a very crude way to resolve this issue. The root problem is that Python 2.7.10 is attempting to import a module that belongs to 2.7.11; the symbol is defined in 2.7.11 but not 2.7.10. A better solution is to understand why Python 2.7.10 is being invoked at all.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I run into this problem when using Anaconda. Anaconda2.4.1 has scipy-0.16.0 as one of the dependencies, and scipy-0.16.0 requires python 2.7.11. The default python in Anaconda is 2.7.10 (as well as the rest of the dependent libs are using 2.7.10), so that after upgrading to the newest Anaconda, I was unable to use it. While I'm waiting for the official bug fix of Anaconda, I need to run several conda scripts. So I decided to use this crude way to resolve the issue temporarily.

Comment: After installing Dato Launcher I had this issue. After trying many of the options above this helped.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well in MacVim. I solved it by making sure `:python print(sys.path)` is using *system Python* (e.g. `/Library/Python/2.7/...`)

Since I installed MacVim via Homebrew, I just did that by:

1. Spawn a new shell that had `which python` -> `/usr/bin/python`. For my case I needed to remove the `pyenv` line from my `.bash_profile`. If you installed Python via Homebrew you may want to `brew unlink python` first
2. `brew reinstall macvim`

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is caused by `anaconda`, it is unnecessary to remove `//anaconda` directory.

Just open your `~/.bash_profile`, find the line

```
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

and comment it out, then restart your terminal session.

Answer (score 3):

Another quick workaround if you don't mind sticking with Python 2.7.10 is to specify the path of the Python interpreter executable that will be used for the virtualenv. On OSX that path is usually `/usr/bin/python`:

```
virtualenv venv --python=/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't add comment (?) so this just to share my exp., downgrade to 2.7.10 works fr me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after a failed NLTK download, I needed to uninstall anaconda:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/anaconda 
update PATH variable
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I already had tried to create a venv in a folder, and mistakenly was trying to initialize a second one! So I just removed venv directory and re-ran the command. Very likely this is not the answer to this solution, but searching my error brought me here, so it may help some others who are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the symbolic link that was in `/usr/local/bin` and copying the actual python binary, that was pointed to by said link, there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to use PyCharm. Solved by setting "python interpreter" in project configuration to point to the python virtual env I wanted to use, which was an Anaconda env. Somehow the interpreter path was missing the "anaconda" portion of ~/.../anaconda/.../_io.so. No need to uninstall anaconda.