# ImportError: dlopen(...): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder

Tags: python, pip

I'm a beginner of python.
When I try `python chainer/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py`, Error occured.
I want to execute chainer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chainer/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .utils import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

How can I resolve this error??

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386527/symbol-not-found-pycodecinfo-getincrementaldecoder-trying-to-register-a-packa) helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man I got a similar log when trying to make opencv work in Mac Os El Captain. After some time trying I did It by uninstalling numpy from homebrew and then from pip. It looks like they where in conflict. After that just installed through homebrew and it worked.

```
brew uninstall numpy
pip uninstall numpy
brew install numpy
```

If that doesn't try reinstalling python from homebrew and make sure you have xcode command line tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope it helps.