# Failed to start python after installing speech_recognition package

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I've already installed this package (SpeechRecognition) on my laptop, now I'm trying to make it work on my Imac (sierra aswell). 
I followed the installation the same as on the macbook.

But when trying to run the test I get following error.

python -m speech_recognition

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with your Python installation...

Comment: Maybe PATH problems? When '''echo $PYTHONPATH''' I get an empty line as result

Comment: You installed the package with the system python, then tried to use it with a user-installed python. Make sure you install and use the package with the same python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbol not found: \_\_PyCodecInfo\_GetIncrementalDecoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386527/symbol-not-found-pycodecinfo-getincrementaldecoder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to terminal and typing in that:

```
python -m speech_recognition
```

or

```
python3 -m speech_recognition
```

If that's what your running.

it depends what version of python your using, Sierra comes with python IDLE 2.7.10 already installed.

if you download those modules for python it will download them to work with 2.7.10 not the 3.0 + you might be using.

so if you downloaded python3 and are trying to run it with python3 it won't work, only from 2.7.10 so try typing in.

```
python -m speech_recognition
```

Like i suggested and see if it works in the terminal, if it does then it means i was right and python 2.7.10 will work with it.