# Import Error Symbol not found: __PySlice_AdjustIndices

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, importerror

I am doing some beginner Selenium to automate a task in the browser. I have installed Selenium using `pip install selenium` and I know it installed successfully because I saw the following message: `Successfully installed selenium-3.9.0`.

Okay so that's clear Selenium is up and working.

I want to run this python file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
```

However, when I run this using the terminal, I get the following error:

```
mustafas-mbp:PlayDivya mustafahoda$ python playDivya.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playDivya.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 22, in <module>
    import httplib as http_client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 69, in <module>
    from array import array
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PySlice_AdjustIndices
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
```

Any help would be super helpful. This is a very simple script and I have no idea why this is happening!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playDivya.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
.
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

### Reasons and Solution

- This issue can arise when you install a new version of python. In those cases you may need to run `hash -r python` to tell bash to reset the **cached** location to the python executable.
- If `hash -r pytho`n says too many args then you can use `rehash` command.
- As per the discussion [Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386527/symbol-not-found-pycodecinfo-getincrementaldecoder) the issue occurs when *Python* is updated from `Python` **2.7.10** to **2.7.11**.
- If you are using conda package you need to run `conda install python=2.7.10` which will solve this problem.
- Even downgrading `Python` to **2.7.10** will also work.
- The best solution would be [*Re-Installing Selenium*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium/48269228#48269228).

Comment: Yes thank you so much! the first suggestion worked `hash -r python`.

Comment: Faced a similar issue when importing urllib2 which again depends on array package. The above answer helped.