# Python - ImportError: Symbol not found. Miceforest

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, symbol-not-found, miceforest

I am trying to import the miceforest package after installing it, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[6], line 1
    import miceforest as mf

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/miceforest/__init__.py:12
    from .utils import ampute_data, load_kernel

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/miceforest/utils.py:4
    import blosc

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/blosc/__init__.py:12
    from blosc.blosc_extension import (

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/blosc/blosc_extension.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: __PyByteArray_empty_string
  Referenced from: <330342D0-A772-3EAC-8AD1-93294FCC9117> /Users/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/blosc/blosc_extension.cpython-311-darwin.so
  Expected in:     <D9229D7D-8F7E-3E8F-A88E-15125158BCAE> /Users/local/anaconda3/lib/libc++.1.0.dylib
```

I already tried to `hash -r python` as suggested in [this answer]:([Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386527/symbol-not-found-pycodecinfo-getincrementaldecoder))

But then I get: `hash: too many arguments`
Just running `rehash` didn't do the trick either.

If I run `which python`: `/Users/local/anaconda3/bin/python`.
I am using python version 3.11.6.
I reinstalled my Anaconda a few days earlier.

Also not very experienced with programming, so please help me :)